# Chrome Memory/Garbage Collection Issue

Tags: javascript, memory, google-chrome, garbage-collection

I am having memory/garbage collection issues with Chrome

I am working on a photo uploading site which allows my client to drag and drop photos to upload using HTML5 and file API, so this wont work in IE. it only works in Chrome and FF. I haven't tested in Safari, Opera yet.

I am not using any JS frameworks and my example is less than 80 lines of code, so it's really easy to follow.

Here is my example: http://seesquaredphoto.com/testPreview.html

If you drag and drop a handful of JPG photos (4-5MB each) into the box you will see the previews load and in windows task manager, you can see the memory usage climb for that window. If you click the "Clear Images" button, the images are deleted.

If you do this in FF, after a few seconds, the memory returns to back what it was before you previewed the images. However in chrome, the memory does not drop.

Any ideas? Am i doing something wrong or is this a chrome bug?

Thanks.
Here is the code if you dont want to view source the link above:

**Javascript**:

```
var upload = {        
    uploadFiles : function(event) {
        var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        var imageType = /image.*/;
        for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            var file = files.item(x);
             if (!file.type.match(imageType) || file.fileName.toUpperCase().indexOf(".JPG")!=file.fileName.length-4) {  
               continue;  
             }      

            var s = document.createElement("span"); 
            s.className = "imgS";   
            var img = document.createElement("img");  
            img.className = "preview";  
            img.src = "";  

            s.appendChild(img);
            document.getElementById("DDCont").appendChild(s);
            loadPreview(img,file);
        }
    }
}; 
function loadPreview(img,file){
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
function init(){
    var container = document.getElementById('DDCont');
    container.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
        }, 
        false
    );
    container.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            event.preventDefault();
        },  
        false
    );
    container.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            event.preventDefault();
        },  
        false
    );
    container.addEventListener("drop", upload.uploadFiles, false);
}   
function clearImages(){
    cont = document.getElementById("DDCont");
    while(cont.childNodes.length>0) {
         cont.removeChild(cont.childNodes[0]); 
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="DDCont" style="width:800px; height:600px; border:3px solid #333333; overflow:auto;"></div>
<input type="button" value="Clear Images" onclick="clearImages()"/>
```

Comment: Post your code here. 10% of SO's users are on iOS and can't see it.

Comment: And following on from Radek's comment, StackOverflow should stand alone. External links can be deleted or get moved. And just generally, people shouldn't have to go elsewhere to read your question.

Comment: Where are you removing the event listeners? Just because you remove an element from the DOM doesn't mean all the events are tossed as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah this is a big problem for me as well,
It seems that modern browsers dont free up resources, especially with Images. I think this should be a focus considering the massive amounts of Ajax pages, keeping state, and allowing the user to NOT refresh the page.

Luckily, with HTML5 video, you can achieve this by first changing the src

```
video.src=" ";
video.load();
```

If you do this before removing video elements, the memory is cleared.

Unfortunately I have no found a way to do this with Images, If it is found I would love to know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your right, I believe it happens to any DOM removal, the memory isn't freed in Chrome. Same thing happens with Canvas:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40178

Perhaps you can submit a bug report (http://crbug.com/new), and after you do that, I will cc the appropriate team for more triaging.

Thanks!

Comment: submitted the bug
[http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72146](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72146)

Comment: Thanks added appropriate tags to it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this have being fixed in recent versions of chromium (at least the video memory leak).

The fix can be found in chrome 49 and I believe this was the exact commit that fixed it: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d13710832e9d0e6302cf8388cda94a7a780d8664%5E%21/#F0

This means that the source hack is no longer needed.

Comment: It is really good to see that you made time to contribute an answer to an old question. Although the supposed fix might help resolve the problem - it is always best to include the key aspects of the fix/solution in your answer so that even if the link goes down, your answer can still be useful.

Comment: Hey @ishmaelMakitla the fix is implicit in chromium and it just mean that the issue should not happen any more. The link is just a reference in case you want to do extra investigation.